# Cannot install Windows Server 2016 on 2008 R2 Hyper-V due to MACHINE CHECK EXCEPTION stop error

Tags: hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2016, stoperror

I'm trying to create a Windows Server 2016 instance on Hyper-V 2008 and it fails to boot from the ISO because of a stop error "MACHINE CHECK EXCEPTION". Is installing 2016 not possible on an OS as old as 2008 R2?

I've tried installing the same ISO on Windows 10 HyperV and that works OK.

Is the only solution to upgrade the host OS to a later version?

Comment: I seriously doubt that Windows Server 2016 is a supported Hyper-V guest in Windows Server 2008.

Comment: This article is from 2014, but my guess is that it's still valid. - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc794868(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: OK thanks. I had incorrectly assumed that virtualisation meant the host OS didn't really care about what it was actually hosting, but clearly it's a factor.

Comment: @NickG That's one of the differences between using a hypervisor and using virtualization.

Answer (score 4):

According to the official document, Server 2016 is not a supported guest OS on Server 2008 R2:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc794868(v=ws.10).aspx

You need Server 2012 R2 or Win8.1 Hyper-V host:

https://technet.microsoft.com/library/dn792027.aspx